# How do I change the apple ID assigned to an IPA file?

Tags: file, itunes, ipa, editing

I noticed when pushing an IPA to a device through iTunes that each app file is assigned to my ID or whoever downloaded it, and I can see that in some places when unpacking the "zip" that is the IPA that there is the email assigned.
How would I change what account iTunes will think is assigned to the file?
Is it only email adress? Is my password in there? Is there a string of characters assigned to my user ID as well? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you're looking for a method to remove the metadata from an IPA file. Depending on your system, there are many programs for this, such as [Subler](https://subler.org).

However, if you happen to be looking for a way to remove metadata that occurs when you push the IPA to a device, you could edit (unzip) the IPA and remove the `iTunesMetadata.plist`, then repack the IPA (zip and change extension to `.ipa`)